# Hide/show outputs Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, show-hide

I am trying to find out how to show and hide my outputs like graphics and tabels each time when the user change something in the widgets. For instance I have a `sliderInput` for my variable called "gender" with 2 choices : male and female. I also have a button which executes estimations when the user click on it. I want to hide the outputs each time when the user changes at least one choice between the different widgets.  For instance after one estimation the user decides to change only the level of education and when the user click on the `sliderInput` box, I would like to hide the previous results.

I tried to use the R package `shinyjs` and the functions `hide`/`show` but they are not working for outputs.

Do you have any idea how to do it without using shinyjs package?

Here is a part of my code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    fluidRow( 
      column(4, wellPanel(

  fluidRow(
      column(5,selectInput("gender",
                          label = div("Sexe",style = "color:royalblue"),
                          choices = list("Male", "Female"),
                          selected = "Female")),

        # other different widjets..        

              column(8, plotOutput('simulationChange')),
              column(4, tableOutput('simulationChangeTable'),
                                    tags$style("#simulationChangeTable table {font-size:9pt;background-color: #E5E4E2;font-weight:bold;margin-top: 121px; margin-left:-30px;overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;text-align:left;align:left;}", 
                                    media="screen", 
                                    type="text/css"), 
                  fluidRow(
                     column(6, tableOutput('simulationChangeEsperance'),
                                    tags$style("#simulationChangeEsperance table {font-size:9pt;background-color: #E5E4E2;font-weight:bold;margin-top: -10px; margin-left:-30px;overflow:hidden; white-space:wrap;word-break: break-word;width:173px;text-align:left;}"))
                  )
              )
            )
        )
     )
    ))  

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
# part of my server.R code
    observe({


   if (input$gender|input$age|input$birthplace|input$education){  
      shinyjs::hide("simulationChange")
      shinyjs::hide("simulationChangeTable")
      shinyjs::hide("simulationChangeEsperance")
      }      
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at conditionalPanel to be used in ui.r

Comment: I'm the author of shinyjs, and it definitely does work with outputs.  I tried running your code to see what the problem is, but the code you gave has too many errors that it's hard to work with. If you could provide a shorter piece of code that is able to run, I can see why your shinyjs::hide() isn't working

Comment: Hi, nice to meet you. Thank you for your answer. I have very longs server.R script and ui.R script. Also, I can not publish everything because I am not allowed. That's why I wrote a part of my code that of course is not working alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by Dieter in the comments you need to use [conditionalPanel](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html). For example, in your ui.R, instead of

```
plotOutput('simulationChange')
```

use

```
conditionalPanel("output.show", plotOutput('simulationChange'))
```

And in your server.R add the following:

```
values <- reactiveValues()
values$show <- TRUE

observe({
    input$gender
    input$age
    input$birthplace
    input$education
    values$show <- FALSE
})

output$show <- reactive({
    return(values$show)
})
```

Also, don't forget to change `values$show`, when clicking on your button:

```
observeEvent(input$button, {
    ...
    values$show <- TRUE
})
```

Comment: In shiny 1.0.5 I had to add `== TRUE` to the condition to make it work. It looked like this: `conditionalPanel("output.show == TRUE", plotOutput('simulationChange'))`

Answer (score 13):

The reason your code didn't work is because you didn't make a call to `useShinyjs()` (if you read the documentation or look at any examples of using shinyjs, you'll see that you HAVE to call `useShinyjs()` in the UI).

I couldn't replicate your code because it had too many errors, but just to demonstrate that it does work with outputs, here's a small example you can run.  In your project, just add `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` somewhere in the UI.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("hideshow", "Hide/show plot"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(100))
  })

  observeEvent(input$hideshow, {
    # every time the button is pressed, alternate between hiding and showing the plot
    toggle("plot")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I know its only an example, but I think people will reference this code, can you also add `show` and `hide` too by checking if the button divides by two or not  `observeEvent(input$hide, { 
    if(input$hide%%2 ==0){show("plot")}
    if(input$hide%%2 !=0){hide("plot")}
  })`

Comment: that's what the `shinyjs::toggle()` function is for :)

Comment: also note there's a `condition` parameter in `toggle()` in case you don't want to alternate every time but instead use an expression that evaluates to true/false to determine if to show or hide

Comment: How to change the text inside the button reactively (change from show to hide and vice versa)?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here don't seem to provide the right/complete answer. The solution is actually quite simple.

You need to use `outputOptions(output, 'show', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)`

Below is a sample code that displays the text inside a `conditionalPanel` if the dropdown selection is 2 and hides if it is 1.

```
  library(shiny)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("num", "Choose a number", 1:2),
    
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.show",
      "The selected number is 2 so this text is displayed. Change it back to 1 to hide."
    )
    
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$show <- reactive({
          input$num == 2 # Add whatever condition you want here. Must return TRUE or FALSE
      })
    
    outputOptions(output, 'show', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  }
    
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```