# R shiny, shinyjs, remove plot and draw it again if button is clicked

Tags: r, shiny, k-means, shinyjs

I have an app that plots the Old Faithul data with k-means clusters once the user clicks on a specific button ("run k-means"). Now, I want to add a button that removes the plot again ("remove plot"). Following [Hide/show outputs Shiny R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136029/hide-show-outputs-shiny-r)
I tried this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
actionButton(inputId = "run_kmeans", label = "run k-means"),
actionButton(inputId = "remove_plot", label = "remove plot"),
conditionalPanel("output.show", plotOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
v <- reactiveValues(show = TRUE)

clusters <- eventReactive(input$run_kmeans, {
kmeans(faithful, 2)
v$show <- TRUE
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(faithful, col = clusters()$cluster)})

output$show <- reactive({
return(v$show)
})

observeEvent(input$remove_plot, {v$show <- 0})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately, now the "run k-means" button does not work anymore. Hence, I also tried it via `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton(inputId = "run_kmeans", label = "run kmeans"),
  actionButton(inputId = "remove_plot", label = "remove plot"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  clusters <- eventReactive(input$run_kmeans, {kmeans(faithful, 2)})
  output$plot <- renderPlot({show(plot(faithful, col = clusters()$cluster))})

  observeEvent(input$remove_plot, {hide("plot")})
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But now the plot is hidden "forever" and not shown again if "run k-means" is clicked - did I place the `show()` function wrongly? Who can help me with either one of the two approaches (or both)?

Comment: place the show call within an observer event like you did for the hide call: `observeEvent(input$run_kmeans, {show("plot")})`

Comment: This did the job.