# hiding a plot in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, show-hide

I'm building a bioinformatics tool with shiny R.

The tool generates multiple plot in the same window with renderplot. I would like to show only some plots ondemand depending on the selection in a selectinput object.

I also tried to use a conditionalPanel but I cannot manage to create a good condition in the ui (input section) to modify the server behavior and to generate a different output in the ui (output section).

Some ideas?

Thank you

Comment: See `hideElement` in the `shinyjs` package.

Comment: I see now this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136029/hide-show-outputs-shiny-r...I solved my problem, thank you